# Outlook 2010 signature doesn't change

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an end user who has multiple email accounts under Outlook 2010, each account with a relevant signature.

When he replies to an email from one of his 'non-default' accounts the appropriate signature does not attach. Instead the signature attached to the default account is attached.

When creating New emails from any account the appropriate signature is applied (when changing the From field).

Any ideas?

His Signatures is set as follows:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is he logged into outlook ?

from a default profile, like his user account?

If so then the signature won't change unless the user changes the to *from address*.

As the default *email address* will be the current logged in outlook profile, hence corresponding to the default signature of that address.

I hope this helps.